# android, how to convert bitmap to file object

Tags: android

I want to convert a bitmap object to a file object. 
However, I want to store the file object on memory, not in SDcard or internal storage, so that I can use the image file without saving in gallery.

The code below is just for acquiring the bitmap and converting it into smaller image

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode != RESULT_OK)
        return;

    if(requestCode == PICK_FROM_CAMERA){

        imageUri = data.getData();



        Cursor c = this.getContentResolver().query(imageUri, null, null, null, null);
        c.moveToNext();
        absolutePath = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA));

        Glide.with(this).load(imageUri).into(image);


        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 4;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(absolutePath, options);



    }
```

Comment: `not in SDcard or internal storage, so that I can use the image file`. Impossible. There are no other places for files.

Comment: Well question worded too difficult.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Hope this will help you

```
private static void persistImage(Bitmap bitmap, String name) {
File filesDir = getAppContext().getFilesDir();
File imageFile = new File(filesDir, name + ".jpg");

OutputStream os;
try {
  os = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
  bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, os);
  os.flush();
  os.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
  Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error writing bitmap", e);
  }
}
```

Comment: @ thanks!!!!!!!!!` ???? How can you approve this solution so loud? You said  `not in SDcard or internal storage`,

Comment: what is bitmap.compress? why this function give JPEG format? and what is 100?

Comment: @roghayehhosseini
its the quality

Comment: how to we create a temp file for a bitmap and post it to server

Answer (score 3):

For those how are looking for Kotlin code to Convert bitmap to File Object. Here is the detailed article I have written on the topic. [Convert Bitmap to File in Android](https://handyopinion.com/convert-bitmap-to-file-in-android-java-kotlin/)

```
fun bitmapToFile(bitmap: Bitmap, fileNameToSave: String): File? { // File name like "image.png"
        //create a file to write bitmap data
        var file: File? = null
        return try {
            file = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + fileNameToSave)
            file.createNewFile()

            //Convert bitmap to byte array
            val bos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, bos) // YOU can also save it in JPEG
            val bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray()

            //write the bytes in file
            val fos = FileOutputStream(file)
            fos.write(bitmapdata)
            fos.flush()
            fos.close()
            file
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            file // it will return null
        }
    }
```