# Bitmap to MultiPartEntity using retrofit

Tags: android, bitmap, retrofit2, multipartentity

Before i will start i see a lot of questions about this but nothing works for me
maybe someone can explained or display it to me how can compress bitmap to MultiPart entity and than send it to the server correct using Retrofit

Comment: what did you try ?

Answer (score 2):

For those who come here for solution, here's mine.

First create a temporary file based on that **bitmap**

[Convert Bitmap to file in Android (Stack Overflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41799695/android-how-to-convert-bitmap-to-file-object/41799811#41799811)

Then get that file and add as multipart file

```
RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
MultipartBody.Part fileBody = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("imageFile", file.getName(), requestFile);
```

Answer (score 1):

First you create a ResponseBody of the file and parse it as a MultipartBody.Part:

```
// build request containing file
RequestBody fileBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
MultipartBody.Part filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", "your_bitmap_file.bmp", fileBody);
```

This *filePart* can then be passed to your Retrofit Service, which should look like this:

```
@Multipart
@POST("/")
Call<ResponseBody> upload(@Part MultipartBody.Part file);
```